# Configure OpenVPN with existing certificate

Tags: linux, openvpn, openssl, open-source, self-signed-certificate

I want to configure OpenVPN with available certificates, without using easy-rsa.

I use openssl to generate private.key and csr.csr. Then I use opensource CA EJBCA to authenticate csr and create a digital certificate of the form ca.p12.

How can I configure openvpn with the above certificates? I have tried configuring in /etc/openvpn/server.conf. I have placed the certificates I had here but still can't configure openvpn.

I used Centos 7.9,EJBCA and Openssl

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem. OpenVPN doesn't care where its certificates come from. We used Microsoft's AD Certificate Services once to issue certificates. That works just as good as EasyRSA or whatever else.

The requirements are:

- There is a CA that signs clients certificates, it must be configured in server's `ca` option (or `<ca>...</ca>` block).
- There is a CA that signs servers certificates, it must be configured in a client's `ca` option (or `<ca>...</ca>` block).

These might be the same CA (usually you do it like that), but it's not required. None of the server or client certificate itself can be self-signed. CA better be self-signed, e.g. not a subordinate of some other CA and in turn it should not sign any subordinate CAs; that calls for problems (like, OpenVPN will trust *all* the descendant certificates of the given CA, which might be not what you want).

PKCS#12 bundles aren't just "form of certificate"; it is a container, possibly encrypted, that has a certificate chain and a private key. So keep those files secure!

You can use PKCS#12 bundles with `pkcs12` option or `<pkcs12>...</pkcs12>` block (file contents encoded as BASE64) in the configuration file. This *replaces all three other crypto-related options* (`ca`, `cert` and `key`). I tried it, it works too. This is covered in `man openvpn`.

Or you can extract certificates and the key out of the bundle using `openssl pkcs12 -in INFILE.p12 -out OUTFILE.crt -nodes` and use them raw.

Comment: Thank you,i had test a againt and it worked